# Auto Import Mysql from XSLX

Tags: php, mysql, database, import

I have datas that will be added monthly, every month I must import more than 30 XSLX! When I am using Navicat I must set the relation from xslx column with mysql table column and I do it repeatedly! It's wasting my time ...
I was wondering that I can import from xlsx to MYSQL automatically, using PHP or Navicat or anything else maybe? Please help me.

---

SOLVED :
I am using SimpleXLSX, it's faster and efficient. Very recommended for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple Perl script that will do the following:

1. Open your Excel file(s) for reading using [DBD::Excel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aExcel) driver.
2. Open MySQL server connection using [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql) driver.
3. Read data from Excel using SELECT and insert data into MySQL using INSERT.
4. Profit! :-)

To make it work on Windows, you should install following free software:

Activestate Perl from http://activestate.com/perl, then DBD::mysql and DBD::Excel as follows:

```
ppm install DBD::Excel
ppm install DBD::mysql
```

And finally, you need to write your Perl script. It should not be very difficult if you follow documentation on links above.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)
Good examples and docs are supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Customize data import once and save template file (import options, field mapping and etc.), then use it many times. It is also possible to use data import in command-line mode.